# Modify VBA code for find and replace to loop through multiple Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops, replace

I have the following code for searching a range of cells in Worksheet called "Front_Wing". It will replace any cell value that matches a value in Worksheet called "Acronyms" Column A with the cell value in "Acronyms" Column B.

I have multiple worksheets, not only "Front_Wing", so I would like to modify this code to loop through multiple worksheets.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim wsR As Worksheet
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, rngR As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim rngReplacement
Dim c As Range
Dim curVal As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Front_Wing")
Set wsR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Acronyms")

i = ws.Rows.Count

With ws
    Set rng = ws.Range("B10", ws.Range("C" & i).End(xlUp))
End With

With wsR
    Set rngR = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & i).End(xlUp))
End With


For Each c In rngR
    curVal = c.Value

    With rng
        .Replace curVal, c.Offset(0, 1).Value, xlWhole, , True

    End With

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to loop through all worksheets, but still only look at "Acronyms"   for the replacing value?

Comment: Not all, only a select few, namely: "Bodywork_Internal", "Bodywork_Lower" & "Chassis". But yes - always looking at "Acronyms"

Comment: Since it's specific worksheets, you can create a loop to go through an array of worksheet names (the names you've given).  That would be the simplest, rather than looping through all and restricting a few sheets, imo.

Comment: Yes Cyril, but it's the code for the loop that I am struggling with

Comment: I was just starting to draft an answer, though I will admit I'm not the best at working with the arrays.  Will need it tested a bit.

Comment: OK thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach, which uses Select Case so just list the sheets you want the macro to cover.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim wsR As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, rngR As Range
Dim rngReplacement
Dim c As Range
Dim curVal As String

Set wsR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Acronyms")

With wsR
    Set rngR = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Bodywork_Internal", "Bodywork_Lower", "Chassis"
            With ws
                Set rng = .Range("B10", .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            End With
            For Each c In rngR
                curVal = c.Value
                With rng
                    .Replace curVal, c.Offset(0, 1).Value, xlWhole, , True
                End With
            Next c
    End Select
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Have slightly updated to shorten a little. Please can you accept the answer - that's how the site works but you don't seem to have done it yet at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()
   Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(0, ws.NAME, "wsName1,wsName2,wsName3") > 0 Then ' wsName1,wsName2,wsName3 = worksheets that you wnat to process
           ProcessYourWorksheet (ws)
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessYourWorksheet(Worksheet As ws)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Richard. Would this not then loop through all worksheets? I want to specify only the select few I have mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: How about `For Each wsName In Array("name1, "name2")`, followed by `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I can't struggle through this with you...

```
Dim i as integer, WSArray as String, LRA as Long, LR as Long

LRA = Sheets("Acronym").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

WSArray=Array("Front_Wing","Bodywork_Internal","Bodywork_Lower","Chassis")

For i = 1 to LR

LR=Sheets(WSArray).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Edit#01, adding something for if statement:
If Sheets(WSArray).Cells(i,1).Value=Application.Index("A1:A" & LRA,Application.Match(Sheets(WSArray).Cells(i,1),Sheets("Acronym").Range("A1:A" & LRA)) Then

    Sheets(WSArray).Cells(i,1).Value=Application.Index("B1:B" & LRA,Application.Match(Sheets(WSArray).Cells(i,1),Sheets("Acronym").Range("A1:A" & LRA))
    Else
    End If

Next i
```

My best guess at specifying the multiple names for sheets.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assuming your code runs, this should iterate through the worksheets
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim wsR As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, rngR As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim rngReplacement
Dim c As Range
Dim curVal As String
'Since wsR is where you get your comparison values, declare it. 

Set wsR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Acronyms")

'This loop will go through each worksheet that is not "Acronym" the rest is the same code as yours. 

For Each ws in Activeworkbook.worksheets

if ws.name <> "Acronyms" then
i = ws.Rows.Count

With wsR
    Set rngR = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & i).End(xlUp))
End With

With ws
    Set rng = ws.Range("B10", ws.Range("C" & i).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each c In rngR
    curVal = c.Value

    With rng
    .Replace curVal, c.Offset(0, 1).Value, xlWhole, , True
End With

Next
end if

next ws
    End Sub
```